# How many buildings or units can be stacked before they reduce their efficiency?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire

I am currently playing Sins of a Solar Empire with all expansions. My question is: how many buildings like Orbital Refinery or Broadcast Towers can be stacked on one planet before some sort of diminishing return kicks in and reduces their efficiency.

Is a similar mechanic in place for capitals and other support ships? Are multiple buildings that give bonuses like Orbital Refinery cumulative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trade Ports can stack linearly, each one giving the same bonus.

TEC and Vasari Orbital Refineries affect their planet and all planets within one jump. In an inhabitable system, the extractors can benefit from up to three refineries, while extractors in an uninhabitable system can benefit from up to four.

Advent Refineries are a bit different. After the Resource Focus research, you can toggle your Trade Ports into Orbital Refineries. This orbital refineries only benefit the planet they are located on, but stack additively. However, because of certain factors, you're usually better off leaving your Trade Ports as Trade Ports.

Broadcast Centers also stack linearly.

Shield Generators and Phase Jump Inhibitors do not stack.

Passive capital ship abilities do not stack.

Comment: Great answer, thanks so far :). Can you add something about support ship stacking (as asked)? For example the tracking link bonus from the TEC Capital?

Comment: Wups, missed that part in the question. There you go. The stacking of passive abilites would be far too powerful. For example, Advent players could just build 16 Halcyon Carriers, giving their fleet a 352% increase in firing rate.

Comment: Glad to help. SoaSE is one of my favorite games. Can't wait for Rebellion to release!